# Maven project on linux machine can't compile when sshed from other machine

Tags: java, linux, maven

I have a maven project on a linux machine and it runs fine when I run mvn package from the linux machine itself. I can build the project and all the good stuff. But, when I ssh to the linux machine from my mac and browse to my maven project, the mvn package command gives me an error. I have pasted the error here -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/launcher/Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.  Program will exit.
```

Comment: You've probably not set the relevant environment variables properly.

Comment: But I am sshing on to the linux machine. If they are set correctly on the linux machine itself (since it runs fine there), shouldn't it run when all I've changed it sshing to it from the mac and running the same command.

Comment: try echoing `echo $M2_HOME` `echo $JAVA_HOME` in both bash session and find the difference

Comment: @RohitPandey - No. It doesn't follow that the environment variables will be the same. It depends on how they are being set.